# Set column table case insensitive oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to make the data in column `NAME` which is in `USERS` table to be case insensitive, how I can do this? I would like to use alter table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name (something to make it case insensitive);
```

Comment: Column _names_ are always case insensitive in SQL. `select column_name from some_table` is the same as `select COLUMN_NAME from some_table`

Comment: It is not clear whether you mean the column name itself case insensitive or the data in the column? 1. For the prior, it is already case insensitive. 2. If you mean the metadata in the dictionary views, then it is case sensitive by default i.e. UPPER. 3. However, if you use double-quotes around them  while creating, you need to always use it for any reference. 4. If you mean case insensitive operation on the column, then look at [**Oracle – Case Insensitive Sorts & Compares**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2014/01/22/oracle-case-insensitive-sorts-compares/)

Comment: No, I mean the data in column 'NAME' for 'USERS' table I want something to set this column to be all the data case insensitive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Column in a table cannot be made `case insensitive`, there is no a such option.
One option is to create a `virtual column`, if you only want to display strings as case insenstive, and search for such insensitive strings, but real data is still stored as case sensitive in the table.
Here is an example:

```
CREATE table TEST(
  name VARCHAR2(100),
  surname varchar2(100)
);

insert into  test values('John', 'Toms' );
insert into  test values('Tom', 'Johns' );

ALTER TABLE test add name_uppercase as (Upper( name ));

select * from test;

NAME       SURNAME    NAME_UPPERCASE     
----------------------------------------
John       Toms       JOHN       
Tom        Johns      TOM  

CREATE INDEX Test_name_upper_ix on test( name_uppercase );

Select * FROM test WHERE name_uppercase = 'TOM';

NAME       SURNAME    NAME_UPPERCASE     
----------------------------------------      
Tom        Johns      TOM
```

Notice that in this example an index is created for such `virtual` column. 
This column can be used like any other ordiary clumn in queries, but it cannot be updated.

---

But if you want to **store data as case insensitive** directly in the table, you can use a trigger to convert data during insertion/updates,  in this way:

```
set define off
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER surname_to_upper
BEFORE insert or update On test FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.surname := Upper( :new.surname );
END;
/
```

---

You can also add a constraint to a table to allow only insertion of uppercase data in some column, like this:

```
alter table test 
add constraint name_must_be_uppercase check( name = upper(name));
```

In this case, when someone tries to insert `name` column that contains small letters, she gets an error:

```
insert into test values( 'Tom', 'Johns' );
SQL Error: ORA-02290: naruszono więzy CHECK (TEST.NAME_MUST_BE_UPPERCASE)
02290. 00000 -  "check constraint (%s.%s) violated"
*Cause:    The values being inserted do not satisfy the named check
```